# Как перенести данные в Jtable когда парсиш страницу

Tags: java

Вот есть код, который парсит нужные мне вещи из сайта, но я не могу занести их в JTable, с чего начать, вот пробую записывать Currency в масив Object а потом выводить. Но столкнулся с проблемой, Object выводит код html, а не данные в нём.Подскажите, может есть другой способ?

```
for (Element line : allLines) {

     Object[] currency   = line.select("td[class = 
       ipsKursTable_currency ipsType_center]").toArray();
     String pokypka = line.select("td[data-rate- 
           type=bid]").text();
     String prodaja  = line.select("td[data-rate- 
                type=ask]").text();
     String commercial = line.select("td[data-rate-type=commercial]").text();   
     String nby = line.select("td[data-rate-type=centralbank").text();
```

Comment: скоро ты побьешь рекорды по количеству заданных вопросов

Comment: @michael_best да я уже 5 дней мучаюсь

Comment: Выучи русский язык и научись хоть как-то грамотно писать вопросы.

Comment: @Flippy тебя забыл спросить что мне учить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил этот вопрос .Вот код. Всё делал через DataTableModel

```
 static String  [] currency = {"Валюта","Купівля","Продаж","НБУ"};
 static DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(currency,0); 
 static JTable jtb = new JTable(dtm); 

 for (Element line : allLines) {
    Vector row = new Vector();

    row.add( line.select("td[class = ipsKursTable_currency ipsType_center]").text() );
    row.add(line.select("td[data-rate-type=bid]").text());
    row.add(line.select("td[data-rate-type=ask]").text());
    row.add(line.select("td[data-rate-type=commercial]").text());
    row.add(line.select("td[data-rate-type=centralbank").text());

    dtm.addRow( row );

}
```